# Feared: Blank frontPage yet accessible backend in joomla 1.5.22

Tags: joomla

I am no expert in Joomla... :)
On my local station using XAMMP, my Joomla 1.5.22 site is running fine but when I upload it to our server online, my problem began, when I visit the frontpage it pulled out nothing but I can still access its backend. I tried to search all over the net, I did some suggested fix but still failed :(

Comment: `I did some suggested fix but still failed` >> what have you actually tried then? Please mention in your question everything you have tried so a possible alternative can be suggested

Comment: Hi, I tried copying new files to my root directory but I did it cautiously since the site has been developed since 2010 I think, I tried to upgrade also, uninstall some plugins.. and more, I forget now since I am working with these since last month then I stop for 2 weeks then I continued:)

Comment: Well first of all, update to Joomla 1.5.26 as it's the latest version of the 1.5 series. Ensure you have edited the settings in the `configuration.php` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just get my site back, I just learned that a depreciated module caused the problem, because our server has been upgraded, so I just disabled all my modules on site then single by single I enable it again and find the module that caused the problem, which I did, I'm now replacing that depreciated module with new extension so that the site will be working back.

-- Update --
Now my site is back, I just found out that GD library is not installed on PHP, that's why it shows blank page in the first place, PHEW!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look for error log in the root folder of your Joomla install, that will give you a hint on why this is happenning.

Also, instead of copying the files and database manually use Akeeba Backup extension for backing up complete site (all files and database) in a single archive.  Then use Akeeba Kickstart script for restoring.  Akeeba Kickstart will automatically change all configurations needed to run your site on the new server.  The extension and the script are free and the process is very simple, look for Youtube videos that show the backup / restore process step by step.

Good luck.